# I am applying a classifier model to a pandas series with its corresponding series and getting this error, how do i fix this? pls hep

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, classification, xgboost

I was working on a model to analyse headlines and return  -1,0, +1 depending on hwo negative, neutral or positive it is. I used kaggle to find datasets and put two together. but when i'm trying to apply the xgboost classifier it gives me an error. I'm pretty new at this would appreciate some help.

```
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_excel('/content/OP.xlsx')


spec_chars = ["!",'"',"#","%","&","'","(",")",
              "*","+",",","-",".","/",":",";","<",
              "=",">","?","@","[","\\","]","^","_",
              "`","{","|","}","~","–"]
for char in spec_chars:
    df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace(char, ' ')

df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.split().str.join(" ")
df = df.dropna()

df.head()
y_axis = df.iloc[:,0]
x_axis = df.iloc[:,1]

#Applying Model
import xgboost as xg

model = xg.XGBClassifier()

model.fit(x_axis,y_axis)
```

The error was this :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e21553eb7329> in <module>()
      3 model = xg.XGBClassifier()
      4 # Call the 'fit()' function with the 'x_fft_train_res' and 'y_fft_train_res' NumPy arrays as input.
----> 5 model.fit(x_axis,y_axis)
      6 # Make predictions on test data by calling the 'predict()' function with 'x_fft_test' data as input.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    717             evals = ()
    718 
--> 719         self._features_count = X.shape[1]
    720 
    721         if sample_weight is not None:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your data is only 1 dimension and it should be 2 dimension .

try this:

```
y_axis = df.iloc[:,0:0]
x_axis = df.iloc[:,1:1]
```

Comment: for example if your code is

```data=pd.DataFrame([{'a':[1,2,3]},{'b':[4,5,6]},{'c':[7,8,9]}])
print(data.iloc[:,0].shape)
print(data.iloc[:,0:0].shape)
```

the output will be 

```
(3,)
(3, 0)

```